# Operand data type datetime is invalid for avg operator error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table that contain datetime field on it. Is that possible to show the average from datetime each month?

The result is something like this

```
Year | Month | Avg
2002 | Dec   | 178
2003 | Jan   | 103
2003 | Feb   | 205
2003 | March | 200
```

I've try `AVG(OrderDate)` but is always show error

> Operand data type datetime is invalid for avg operator.

The fields on my table are OrderDate and Product. I want to Average the product that ordered each month.

Comment: What do you want to average? Can you provide sample data?

Comment: So you want to get the average number of products ordered per month? Your question is still unclear to me.

Comment: what does the date field look like in your table ..e.g, 10/15/2015 or .....

Comment: @FelixPamittan Yeah, something like that. I'm really sorry because English is not my main language.

Comment: @NullSoulException like this : 2015-02-23 15:32:24.853

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  You mention `AVG(FieldName)`, but there is nothing called `FieldName` in the sample data.  You mention average of a `datetime` value, but your sample data has no `datetime` values.

Comment: @JTR, does this help? `SELECT
 [Year] = YEAR(OrderDate),
 [Month] = DATENAME(MONTH, OrderDate),
 [Avg] = AVG(Product)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY
 YEAR(OrderDate),
 DATENAME(MONTH, OrderDate)`

Comment: You want to get the find the average "products_sold/month" .. for each product type or for all products...

Comment: @GordonLinoff umm.. sorry, forgot to update that `AVG(FieldName)` is `AVG(OrderDate)` the OrderDate type is DateTime

Comment: can we see what an insert statement looks like in your table or the DDL of the table

Comment: In your example, what do the numbers 178,103,205 and 200 represent? Are they the number of products ordered for the month?

Comment: @Nerdwood 178, 103, 205, 200 is average quantity from Products per month, but I don't have quantity field in my table.

Comment: If your database does not store quantities, you cannot get an average of the quantities. Do you store the quantity somewhere else? Perhaps in an Order table or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to find the average number of products ordered within the month, something like this might work (but I don't know your database structure):

```
SELECT YEAR(OrderDate) AS [Year], DATENAME(month, OrderDate) AS [Month], AVG(Product) AS [Avg]
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), DATENAME(month, OrderDate)
```